# Change onclick to open in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

So I have a button on a website that looks like this;

```
 <input type="submit" class="MainButton" title="Change" id="ch01_changebutton" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.websiteurl.com'; return false;" value="Change" name="ch01$changebutton">
```

I'm wanting to use greasemonkey so I can open that url of the button in a new window.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried messing around with this but no luck:
[Using Javascript to click on a given button AND have it open in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579613/using-javascript-to-click-on-a-given-button-and-have-it-open-in-a-new-window)
(doesnt even work for that website example on there for me)

Comment: Are you trying to submit a form as well as open a new window on clicking the button?

Comment: Why input type submit?

Comment: @ Chinni, no it just opens that link only. TY @Munawir for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location` sets the url of your current window. To open a new window, you need to use `window.open`. This should work:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("ch01_changebutton");
var x = btn.getAttribute("onclick");
x = x.replace("location.href=","open(");
x = x.replace(";",",'_blank');");
btn.setAttribute("onclick",x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using

```
<a href="https://www.websiteurl.com" target="_blank">
```

without JavaScript, but if there is a form you need to submit it by clicking the button, this is the correct way of opening a new window using JavaScript:

```
window.open("https://www.websiteurl.com");
```

Comment: Since you mentioned greasemonkey I'm assuming that you don't have control over the page's initial markup. Using `window.open` should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a javascript functon to change location, and have the button fire that instead.

```
var changeLocation = function(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

then in your onclick:

```
onclick="changeLocation('www.url.com'); return false;"
```

BTW: some browsers do not like onclick. Take a look at [add onclick event to newly added element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript)